# Compiling pcl_trunk/visualization

Tags: ros, visualization, pcl, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just cloned pcl1.6(https://bitbucket.org/bhaskara/perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable) in my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

And I want to modify the visualization tool (visualization), which is located at /pcl16/pcl_trunk/.

I tried compiling it with rosmake but I wasn't successful.
Nothing happens when I compile it. What is the right way to compile it?
Do I need to modify any of the CMakeList.txt, manifest.xml files.

Confituration:
ROS fuerte
Ubuntu 11.10

Thank You

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37472/compiling-pcl_trunk/visualization/) by [OliR](https://answers.ros.org/users/2734/olir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PCL trunk builds the stand-alone version, not the one that works with ROS. The ROS sources (for PCL 1.5) are in https://github.com/wg-debs/pcl

This is a huge mess. I hope we can fix it in Groovy.

UPDATE: There is an interim PCL 1.7 solution in [perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable](http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_fuerte_unstable/). Follow the recently-updated "Integration with ROS" directions in the [PCL Downloads page](http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3